# Erro A coluna 'EXEMPLO' é inválida na lista de seleção porque não está contida em uma função de agregação nem na cláusula GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

Olá, amigos. Estou tentando realizar uma consulta no SQL SERVER que funcionava perfeitamente no SQLite. Alguém sabe como posso fazer ela funcionar?

Consulta:

```
SELECT B.CLIENTE, A.CODCLI, SUM(A.VALOR-A.VALORPAGO) AS 'A RECEBER'
FROM ARGCONTASRECEBER A
INNER JOIN ARGCLIENTE B
ON A.CODCLI = B.CODCLI
WHERE A.VALORPAGO < A.VALOR
GROUP BY A.CODCLI
```

Erro:

> Mensagem 8120, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1 A coluna
>   'ARGCLIENTE.CLIENTE' é inválida na lista de seleção porque não está
>   contida em uma função de agregação nem na cláusula GROUP BY.

Grato desde já!

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa inserir a coluna cliente no seu GROUP BY, a query atualizada fica da seguinte forma:

```html
SELECT B.CLIENTE, A.CODCLI, SUM(A.VALOR-A.VALORPAGO) AS 'A RECEBER' FROM ARGCONTASRECEBER A INNER JOIN ARGCLIENTE B ON A.CODCLI = B.CODCLI WHERE A.VALORPAGO < A.VALOR GROUP BY B.CLIENTE, A.CODCLI
```